# How to send parameter with GET request using retrofit2 in android?

Tags: android, json, get, retrofit2, spinner

Gud Evening to all Folks...
i'm newbie working with retrofit now what i want to achieve i have a spinner where multiple students exists now what i want to get the exam result in new activity with the selected student in other words i only want exam result whom student is selected in spinner.
MY Spinner Url

```
http://example.com/web_service/test.php?call=view_children&branch=22&cellno=03016138662
```

Spinner Json

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "Sr": 1,
      "std_name": "Ahmad Nafees",
      "father_name": "Atif Majeed",
      "std_id": 19399,
      "std_img": "https://example.com/EduPortal/Production/students_pics/",
      "std_class": null,
      "std_section": "PSP ",
      "std_class_id": 155,
      "std_section_id": 244
    },
    {
      "Sr": 2,
      "std_name": "Khajida Atif",
      "father_name": "Atif Majeed",
      "std_id": 28684,
      "std_img": "https://example.com/EduPortal/Production/students_pics/",
      "std_class": null,
      "std_section": "Nursery",
      "std_class_id": 156,
      "std_section_id": 245
    }
  ]
}
```

Exam Json Url

```
http://example.comweb_service/test.php?call=view_results&session_id=5&branch=22&student=19399
```

As you can see spinner json had a parameter called stu_id and in exam json url student=19399
so i want to replace student id to get the selected student result..How can i achieve this or is this possible?
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Put your content properly

Comment: Are you still looking for answer or is it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a POST request with retrofit, so in the backend you will have a route for accepting this data. To do a simple POST request with Retrofit you can do something like this:
Create an interface for your requests

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("register_user")
    Call<RegisterUser> registerUser(@Field("name") String name,
                                    @Field("email") String email,
                                    @Field("password") String password);
```

and a service for retrieving the data

```
public void signUpUser(Callback<RegisterUser> callback, String name, String email, String password) {
        Call<RegisterUser> call = apiService.registerUser(name, email, password);
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
```

and finally go to your activity:

```
private void registerUser(final String name, final String email, final String password) {
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        Callback<RegisterUser> callback = new Callback<RegisterUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegisterUser> call, Response<RegisterUser> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "user registered" +response.body());
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println(response.body());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegisterUser> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        userService.signUpUser(callback, name, email, password);
    }
```